# Store daterangepicker values in session

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, daterangepicker

I am using [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and attempting to get it's values to stick across views in my rails app.

I've written a javascript function to set the value in the session and retrieve the values when present:

```
var stickyDate = function() {
  // store the current values of the datepicker
  var startDate = $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').startDate._d;
  var endDate = $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').endDate._d;
  // check to see if there are already stored dates in the session
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('stickyStartDate') === null) {
    // if there are none, set the current start and end dates in the session
    sessionStorage.setItem('stickyStartDate', startDate);
    sessionStorage.setItem('stickyEndDate', endDate);
  } else {
    // if the values are present in the session then update the date picker
    $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(sessionStorage.getItem('stickyStartDate'));
    $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(sessionStorage.getItem('stickyEndDate'));
  }
};
```

I know this is really not optimized but I am unsure to begin with just how to acheive this functionality. This is not working as it is.

Comment: I believe the problem is with my setting the start and end dates. The format is incorrect.

Comment: I can't seem to set any date with the daterange control, are you able to change the date via code at all?